# How to covert the ecore model supported by the eclipse to xmi file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, enterprise-architect, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have the Enterprise architect tool.Using that tool i can export the class diagram as ecore file and use in my eclipse work-space.But if i try to import the same ecore in Enterprise architect tool it supports importing of only xml and xmi files. So is there any plugins in eclipse to support for converting the ecore model to xmi or xml which is valid for the Enterprise architect tool or is there any way to import the ecore file to Enterprise architect tool.

Thanks in advance

Comment: each .ecore file is actually a xmi file, (you can open it as text in eclipse). Have you tried to rename your .ecore file to .xmi?

Answer (score 1):

EA can't read Ecore, but it can read .emx / .uml2. So if you can export your model in .uml2 format from Eclipse, EA can read that.

Comment: Is there any way to export the Ecore as .emx/.uml2

Comment: That's a different question. Please ask it separately.